# How do I fade the corners/edges/borders of a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I was unable to find this on the forums so I decided to post this.

I have a UIImageView with the following code which fades the images from one another.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", @"image4.jpg", @"image5.jpg", nil];
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:0]];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionPhotos) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

// Rounds corners of imageview
CALayer *layer = [imageview layer];
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setCornerRadius:5];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)transitionPhotos{

if (photoCount < [imageNames count] - 1){
    photoCount ++;
}else{
    photoCount = 0;
}
[UIView transitionWithView:imageview
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:photoCount]]; }
                completion:NULL];
}
```

I want to implement a code that will fade the borders of my imageview.

I know I can use the QuartzCore.framework, however I was unable to find a guide how to achieve the result that I want.

What would be the shortest possible code to do such a method?

Comment: You can mask the image view with another image with faded edges.

Answer (score 19):

Have an image containing a mask (blurred rectangle on transparent background):

```
UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
```

create a maskLayer:

```
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskLayer.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;
maskLayer.frame = imageView.bounds;
```

and assign it as mask for your imageView:

```
imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Edit:
you can create the mask completely by code using the shadow properties of `CALayer`. Just play around with `shadowRadius` and `shadowPath`:

```
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = imageView.bounds;
maskLayer.shadowRadius = 5;
maskLayer.shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectInset(imageView.bounds, 5, 5), 10, 10, nil);
maskLayer.shadowOpacity = 1;
maskLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
maskLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: awsome awsome spend full day, found your answer , life saver , upvoted.You can post it as answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379168/how-to-add-part-of-face-a-to-part-of-face-b-most-importantly-matching-color-ton

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the GPUImage framework, as said [on this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365905/blur-uiimage-outside-of-bounds-photoshop-style)

Here's the code:

```
UIImage sourceImage = ...
GPUImagePicture *imageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:sourceImage];
GPUImageTransformFilter *transformFilter = [GPUImageTransformFilter new];
GPUImageFastBlurFilter *blurFilter = [GPUImageFastBlurFilter new];

//Force processing at scale factor 1.4 and affine scale with scale factor 1 / 1.4 = 0.7
[transformFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(SOURCE_WIDTH * 1.4, SOURCE_WIDTH * 1.4)];
[transformFilter setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7, 0.7)];

//Setup desired blur filter        
[blurFilter setBlurSize:3.0f];
[blurFilter setBlurPasses:20];

//Chain Image->Transform->Blur->Output        
[imageSource addTarget:transformFilter];
[transformFilter addTarget:blurFilter];
[imageSource processImage];

UIImage *blurredImage = [blurFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Answer (score -1):

For rounded corners you need to modify below code:-

```
 imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
 imageView.layer.clipsToBounds = YES;
```