# how to add part of Face A to Part of face B, most importantly matching color tones

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-graphics, face-detection

i have been successful in detecting faces, cropping and pasting in new imageHow ever i am looking a way to mix color tone of face A to Face B.
[image]

So, if you look and face b, cropped image color tone not matching to face B face color.
how can i do this to max % matching.
It would be good to have exact solution, however links or approach will be appreciated. I can provide code for cropping and pasting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it seemed to be helpful for you, fading the edges of the images as described in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24722397/3659846 could be a good thing.

To provide a bit more of an answer to your specific question, I'd try calculating the average color value of one image and then calculate some delta values by which to adjust every pixel of the other image to get the same average color value. This will of course not be perfect, since you might want to find a way to limit it to skin-colors only, but it should give you a starting point...